# i am declaring edittext under linearlayout when i scroll the edittext i want to see lastline

Tags: android, android-edittext

//i am declaring edittext under linearlayout when i scroll the edittext i want to see lastline,but when i am scrolling its not getting lastline how can view all the text under layout when i am moving.and i want to remove the space front and back space to gallery how can i remove
    i am attaching screenshot[image]

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/edittext"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="15dp"
        android:background="#FFFFFF"
        android:focusable="false"
        android:textColor="#666669"
        android:textSize="20dp"
        android:textStyle="normal" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/llexport"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        android:layout_weight="4" >

        <SeekBar
            android:id="@+id/seekbardown"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:progressDrawable="@drawable/styled_progress"
            android:thumb="@drawable/playprogressionhandle"
            android:thumbOffset="-1px" />
    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: its scrolling but i want to see lastline above the seekbar,i want to get the entaire text above the layout.

Answer (score 0):

//do your edittext above your linear layout

```
 <EditText
            android:id="@+id/edittext"
android:layout_above="android:id="@+id/llexport"
```

.....

```
//to show last text from your edittext
android:paddingBottom="50dp"
```

Comment: when i am declaing like this it is getting,but my requirement is i want to show the text under the that layout,when i am declaring like this its not showing text.

Comment: then you need to give padding bottom for your edittext.

Comment: if i am giving padding bottom to editext then text in not visible under seekbar layout.

Comment: you need remove the layout_above, keep as its before and do only padding bottom.

Answer (score 0):

Please check below code and try it instead of your Edittext.

```
<EditText
            android:id="@+id/edittext"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_above="android:id="@+id/llexport"
            android:paddingBottom="5dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="15dp"
            android:background="#FFFFFF"
            android:focusable="false"
            android:textColor="#666669"
            android:textSize="20dp"
            android:textStyle="normal" />
```